# How to get attribute of a sqlalchemy query object

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

The below code is written in views.py in the flask framework:

view.py :

```
motions = db.session.query(
    Motion.id,
    Motion.summary,
    Motion.motion_type_id,
    Motion_Type.description,
    Motion_Type.id,
    Motion.mp_op_type,
    Motion.judge_id,
    Judge.id,
    Judge.name,
    Motion.case_id,
    Case.id,
    Case.summary,
    Case.case_type_id,
    Case_Type.description,
    Case_Type.id,
    Motion.ruling_id,
    Ruling.name,
    Ruling.id
).filter(
    Case.id == Motion.case_id
).order_by(
    Judge.name,
    Case_Type.description,
    Ruling.name,
    Motion_Type.description
)
```

How do I get the attribute in the query? I want to get something like:

```
for x in motions:
    print(x.ruling())
```

However, my error was that there is no attribute called 'ruling' in 'motions' in views.py. So my question is, how to get the attribute in the query? Am I missing something, or like, am I supposed to call something from models.py or instantiate something on the html template? Very confused.

Comment: try: `motions = db.session.query(...).all()` and `for row in motions: print(row.ruling)` note that ruling is not called as a function here

Comment: @Nullman if ruling is not called as a function, what is it called as?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't really using the Query API as designed. It seems like you're looking for something like this (assuming your relationships are setup properly in your models):

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
motions_query = db.session.query(
    Motion
).join(
    Motion.case
).join(
    Case.judge
).join(
    Case.case_type
).options(
   sa.orm.contains_eager(Motion.case).contains_eager(Case.judge),
   sa.orm.contains_eager(Case.case_type)
).filter(
    Case.id == Motion.case_id
).order_by(
    Judge.name,
    Case_Type.description,
    Ruling.name,
    Motion_Type.description
)

for motion in motions_query:
    print(motion.case.summary)
    print(motion.case.judge.name)
```

Comment: If I simply use .query(...) then I won't need to join, right? Also, what is sa.orm.contains_eager ? Is there a documentation for it? I'm new to sqlAlchemy and would like to keep the query simply and minimal. My previous query ```motions = db.session.query(Motion.motion_type, Motion.judge, Motion.ruling, Case.case_type, MotionCode.motioncode_text).filter(Case.case_number == Motion.case_number, Motion.motion_type == MotionCode.motioncode_key).order_by(Motion.judge, Case.case_type, MotionCode.motioncode_text, Motion.ruling)``` worked so I changed my query by referencing this.

Comment: You'll want to read up on loading strategies for extraneous relationships. It'll help you build performant queries that aren't susceptible to n+1 performance issues. contains_eager https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager